Outward pointing normal Tetrahedron
For this tetrahedron I need to write down the order of the vertices such that the normal vector points out of the tetrahedron.
For the base DAC, I have drawn the normal vector pointing outwards downwards. Is this correct - is this the outward pointing vector?
Using the right hand grip rule, for the normal to point downwards, the vertice order must be clockwise, i.e. from C to A to D.
Is this correct?


Correct. The outward pointing normal is the normalized cross product $\frac{\vec{CA}\times\vec{AD}}{\|\vec{CA}\times\vec{AD}\|}.$

I was unsure because my notes said different. Thanks.
